# Hifiberry or Standard out?

Tags: hifiberry

Perhaps a non-technical questions but more a matter of opinion, but how far does the sound capability of the RP3 go w.r.t. sound output? I have two larger shelf speakers and an amplifier for about 50 watt. Would you recommend getting the HifiBerry extension or is that only 4 Audiophiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the standard output, see if you like it. If you don't, get something more expensive.

Beyond that, any reply you'll get will be purely subjective; the objective measurements (SNR, frequency range, etc.) are all available at the respective spec sheets.

Comment: Thanks, should have been obvious to me. I was expecting an obvious answer, something like: "Yes, you sound quality will improve 10 fold and we have measured this like this and that" answer.... I guess it is not that simple. :)